# File Problems Java

Tags: java, file

I am struggling to understand what i am doing wrong here. I have checked many times the file does exist and i cant get the For loop to find it. Debugging this section of code it says the path for the variable "folder" but says the filePath is null for that variable. I am very confused any help would be amazing.

```
String path = varablePath1;
File folder = new File(path);

if (folder.exists()){
    System.out.println("got folder");
}

File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();

for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {
    if (listOfFiles[i].isDirectory()) {
        String FileNames = listOfFiles[i].getName();
        FileWriter fw1 = new FileWriter(file1, true);
        BufferedWriter bw1 = new BufferedWriter(fw1);
        bw1.write(FileNames);
        bw1.newLine();
        bw1.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is `file1` declared and defined?

Comment: Post full piece of Code please

Comment: file1 is declared as a varable with a path above the main froblem is that it wont go in the for loop doe to it not being able to get the listFiles() on folder

Comment: initialize  File file1=null; after method . or else better post full code

Comment: what is folder.exists() returning ? and what is folder.listFiles() returning ?

Comment: they are both returning null but "folder" is returning the path en tended

Comment: if the path of the folder is wrong then u should get false when folder.exists() is called not null. pls check value of the variable path or print that value there itself.

Answer (score 0):

what about the else piece in that verification, i.e:

```
    if (folder.exists()){
        System.out.println("got folder");
    }
    else {

    File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();

    for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {
        if (listOfFiles[i].isDirectory()) {
            String FileNames = listOfFiles[i].getName();
            FileWriter fw1 = new FileWriter(file1, true);
            BufferedWriter bw1 = new BufferedWriter(fw1);
            bw1.write(FileNames);
            bw1.newLine();
            bw1.close();
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: i want it to go into that folder if it exists so i have tried if(!(folder.exists)){ stuff in here} but doesn't make a difference

Comment: try giving full path to the file1

Answer (score 0):

you can Check Folder and File form Code and if Folder then get list of Folder and Write Using `BufferedWriter`. it works fine . please Check if any updation want .

```
public class Check {
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
    File f = null;
    String path = "/home/ananddw";
    f = new File(path);

    if (f.isDirectory()) {
        System.out.println("if");
        File[] ss = f.listFiles();
        for (File file : ss) {
            if (file.isFile()) {
                String FileFinalName = file.getName();
                System.out.println(file.getName());

                FileWriter fw1 = new FileWriter(file, true);
                BufferedWriter bw1 = new BufferedWriter(fw1);
                bw1.write(FileFinalName);
                bw1.newLine();
                bw1.close();
            }
        }
    } else if (f.isFile()) {
        System.out.println("elkse");

    }

}
}
```